# Duda con colas en c++

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos, push, queue

Hola buen dia al que lea esto, mi duda es con respecto a una parte del codigo que inserta elementos a la cola, el codigo en cuestion es este:

```
void pushCola(Nodo *&frente,Nodo *&fin, float n)
{
    Nodo *nuevoNodo = new Nodo();

    nuevoNodo->dato = n;
    nuevoNodo->siguiente = nullptr;

    if(frente==nullptr)
    {
        frente = nuevoNodo;
    }

    else
    {
        fin->siguiente = nuevoNodo;
    }


    fin = nuevoNodo;

    cout<<"\tElemento "<<n<<" agregado"<<endl;
    cout<<endl;


}
```

La parte que no logro entender es la del `if` y el `else` en espicifico el `else`.
No comprendo que hace `fin->siguiente = nuevoNodo;` y `fin = nuevoNodo;` se supone que `fin` se posiciona en el ultimo dato agregado, pero bajo mi logica  `fin->siguiente = nuevoNodo;` y `fin = nuevoNodo;` hacen los mismo (aunque ya comprobe que no hacen los mismo al borrar lo del el `else`).
Si alguien me podria explicar la diferencia se lo agradeceria mucho.
Aqui les dejo el codigo completo por si hace falta:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct Nodo
{
    float dato;
    Nodo *siguiente;
};

void menu();
void pushCola(Nodo *&, Nodo *&, float);
void mostrarCola(Nodo *);
void popCola(Nodo *&, Nodo *&, float&);
void limpiarCola(Nodo *&, Nodo*&);

int main()
{
    menu();
    return 0;
}

void menu()
{
    Nodo *frente = nullptr, *fin = nullptr;
    float dato;
    int opcion;

    do
    {
        cout<<"\t\t.:Menu:."<<endl<<endl;

        cout<<"\t1-Insertar elemente en la cola"<<endl;
        cout<<"\t2-Mostrar datos de la cola"<<endl;
        cout<<"\t3-Eliminar el primer elemento"<<endl;
        cout<<"\t4-Limpiar cola"<<endl;
        cout<<"\t5-Salir"<<endl;

        cout<<endl;


        cout<<"\tDigite la opcion que quiere ejecutar: "; cin>>opcion;
        cout<<endl;

        switch(opcion)

        {
            case 1:
                cout<<"Digite el numero: "; cin>>dato;
                cout<<endl;

                pushCola(frente, fin ,dato);

                system("pause");

            break;

            case 2:

                if(frente == nullptr)
                {
                   cout<<"No hay datos que mostar"<<endl;

                }

                else
                {
                    cout<<"Datos guardados: "<<endl;
                    mostrarCola(frente);

                }

                system("pause");
            break;

            case 3:

                if(frente == nullptr)
                {
                   cout<<"No hay datos que eliminar"<<endl;

                }

                else
                {

                    popCola(frente, fin ,dato);



                }
                system("pause");
            break;

            case 4:

                limpiarCola(frente, fin);

                system("pause");

            break;

            case 5:

            break;
        }
        system("cls");
    }while(opcion!=5);
}

void pushCola(Nodo *&frente,Nodo *&fin, float n)
{
    Nodo *nuevoNodo = new Nodo();

    nuevoNodo->dato = n;
    nuevoNodo->siguiente = nullptr;

    if(frente==nullptr)
    {
        frente = nuevoNodo;
    }

    else
    {
        fin->siguiente = nuevoNodo;
    }


    fin = nuevoNodo;

    cout<<"\tElemento "<<n<<" agregado"<<endl;
    cout<<endl;


}

void mostrarCola(Nodo *frente)
{
    if(frente == nullptr)
    {
        cout<<" "<<endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout<<frente->dato<<" ";
        frente = frente->siguiente;
        mostrarCola(frente);
    }
}

void popCola(Nodo *&frente, Nodo *&fin, float &n)
{
    n = frente->dato;

    Nodo *aux = frente;

    if(frente == fin)
    {
        fin = nullptr;
        frente = nullptr;
    }

    else
    {
        frente = frente->siguiente;
    }

    delete aux;

    cout<<"Elemento "<<n<<" eliminado"<<endl;
}

void limpiarCola(Nodo *&frente, Nodo *&fin)
{
    if(frente == nullptr)
    {
        delete frente;
        cout<<"La cola esta limpia"<<endl;
    }

    else
    {
        frente = frente->siguiente;
        limpiarCola(frente ,fin);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que puede verse de tu código, tu `Nodo`:

```
struct Nodo
{
    float dato;
    Nodo *siguiente;
};
```

Tiene conceptualmente este aspecto:

[image]

Es decir: contiene un dato y un puntero hacia el siguiente `Nodo`. De hecho, ese es muy parecido al aspecto de tu lista cuando has añadido un solo elemento: cuando has entrado en la rama del `if` e ignorado la rama del `else`:

```
void pushCola(Nodo *&frente,Nodo *&fin, float n)
{
    Nodo *nuevoNodo = new Nodo();

    nuevoNodo->dato = n;
    nuevoNodo->siguiente = nullptr;

    if(frente==nullptr)
    {
        frente = nuevoNodo;
    }

    ...


    fin = nuevoNodo;

    ...
}
```

[image]

Cuando llamas a `pushCola` sucede lo siguiente:

1. Se crea un nuevo nodo en memoria dinámica:

   ```
   void pushCola(Nodo *&frente,Nodo *&fin, float n)
   {
       Nodo *nuevoNodo = new Nodo();

       nuevoNodo->dato = n;
       nuevoNodo->siguiente = nullptr;

       ...
   }
   ```

   [image]
2. Como `frente` tiene valor, se ejecuta la rama `else` que hace apuntar el siguiente de `fin` al nuevo nodo:

   ```
   void pushCola(Nodo *&frente,Nodo *&fin, float n)
   {
       ...

       else
       {
           fin->siguiente = nuevoNodo;
       }

       ...

   }
   ```

   [image]
3. Para acabar, hace que `fin` apunte al nuevo nodo:

   ```
   void pushCola(Nodo *&frente,Nodo *&fin, float n)
   {
       ...

       fin = nuevoNodo;

       ...

   }
   ```

   [image]

Esto repetido varias veces deja tu pila conceptualmente con este aspecto:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Lo que hace es simple. Para no recorrer toda la lista, guarda un puntero al último elemento.

Para que lo entiendas mejor, usaré tablas con fines ilustrativos. Esta es la lista antes de llamar la función:

| Variable | Frente |  |  | Fin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Nodo** | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |

Así cuando quieres agregar un elemento al final, primero se conecta el nuevo nodo con el que hasta ahora era el último:

```
fin->siguiente = nuevoNodo;
```

| Variable | Frente |  |  | Fin | Nuevo Nodo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Nodo** | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |

Ahora el último nodo es otro así que se actualiza la variable `fin`:

```
fin = nuevoNodo;
```

| Variable | Frente |  |  |  | Fin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Nodo** | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |